# Toggle 4g ON/OFF on Nexus S 4G

Tags: android, android-widget, nexus-s, 4g

I am trying to write an android widget for my Nexus S 4G that toggles 4G ON and OFF.

I am not able to figure out what the "feature" means in ConnectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature (int networkType, String feature) method.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
ConnectivityManager connection = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

connection.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX, "feature");
```

I am trying to figure out what the "feature" parameter is? Android documentation says the interpretation is left to OEM. Does anyone know what it is Samsung Nexus S 4G? Was anyone able to do something like this on Nexus S 4G?

PS: There maybe a few widgets available in the market but I am trying to learn this stuff by coding myself.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to figure out what the "feature" parameter is?

You've already answered that question for yourself.

> Does anyone know what it is Samsung Nexus S 4G?

From [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=909206&page=2) it appears that the string *should* be `"WiMax"` but it looks like this does not work NS4g.